# Google Sheets Script richtext builder output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, richtext

Here's my code, based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffset,-linkurl):

```
const boldStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setUnderline(false)
    .setBold(true)
    .setForegroundColor("#000000")
    .build();

  const testrichtext = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText('testing testing testing')
    .setLinkUrl(0, 5, "https://bar.foo")
    .setTextStyle(7, 10, boldStyle)
    .build();
```

Returns this output which I don't know how to use:

> com.google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.impl.RichTextValueApiAdapter@13134ed6

the `13134ed6` part changes with each run, so I assume it does build something :)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `.build()` return?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply these text styles and rich text values to ranges using the range method [`setRichTextValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue).

You can just apply the style with [`setTextStyle`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#settextstylestyle).

```js
const boldStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setUnderline(false)
    .setBold(true)
    .setForegroundColor("#000000")
    .build();

  const testrichtext = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText('testing testing testing')
    .setLinkUrl(0, 5, "https://bar.foo")
    .setTextStyle(7, 10, boldStyle)
    .build();

function setRichText() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell().setRichTextValue(testrichtext);
}
```